# \foreignlanguage in tabular environment

Tags: tables, babel

`\foreignlanguage` does not work in `tabular`.  How to switch language in `tabular`?

```
\documentclass[spanish,russian]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{misccorr}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{russian}

\foreignlanguage{spanish}{This text is ok.} Здесь всё хорошо.

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\foreignlanguage{spanish}{Not work: some words in spanish.} & А здесь по-русски. \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

pdfLaTeX said:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.15 ...spanish}{Not work: some words in spanish.}
                                                   & А здесь по-ру...

?
```

Answer (score 6):

Oh that's a bit odd, you should maybe report it as a bug in babel, however an extra group fixes it:

```
\documentclass[spanish,russian]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{misccorr}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{russian}

\foreignlanguage{spanish}{This text is ok.} Здесь всё хорошо.

\begin{tabular}{ll}
{\foreignlanguage{spanish}{Not work: some words in spanish.}}& А здесь по-русски. \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that it's specific of Spanish; the error happens when TeX is processing `\es@operators`, which uses `&` for doing a recursion, which obviously doesn't please TeX when found at the outer level in a table.

Comment: I reported this: http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=babel/4374

Comment: Sometimes package writers have some weird ideas ;-) I'm working in a new version of `spanish` and I'll fix this bug.